# Remote desktop client: how to enlarge history list?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows

Anyone knows the setting (in registry perhaps) to enlarge the history list of the remote desktop client?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The history list size is capped at 10 entries. The history items are stored in `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default]` as entries MRU0 through MRU9. Creating an MRU10 entry will not create an 11th history entry.

Answer (score 5):

If you're a heavy user of Remote Desktop, you might check whether [Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rdcman) works best for you.

I don't know if it has a longer history, but it lets you easily define a large list (or lists) of servers to connect to. It's also handy to keep many sessions open at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, for now I'm saving the connections and putting them into a folder from where I can launch flexibly which i want, though there is mRemoteNG which is also pretty nice as long as you don't have too many connections to manage.

Comment: Link has died, here is the new location: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rdcman

Comment: Thanks. You can just edit the answer and put in the new link. I already did that now, I am just writing to encourage you to edit yourself next time, that's the spirit of the site and improvements are always welcome! thanks

Answer (score 2):

A workaround would be to pin the app to the taskbar then change the jumplist settings to something higher than 10.

Comment: Yes, pinning is useful and can elongate the list of connection, but i think it is available starting with W2K8 only, not sure if it was available in W2K3. Thanks for the thought anyway.

Comment: I recognised that the app in the taskbar has indeed more than 10 entries. Also, I found a list of entries in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Servers`. However, not all of the entries are displayed in the taskbar app. Does somebody know why? I have trouble adding one specific entry.

Answer (score 1):

All signs indicate that the history length isn't a configurable setting. Here's a link to a listing of all the possible registry keys that the RDP client checks as it starts, which would include the history length setting if it existed.

http://benryanau.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!E55F3F5F75B5A7BB!176.entry

Comment: Link is dead; is this still applicable information?